# Collapsible panel not expanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, panel

I have a collapsible panel in my code. It expands and collpases on mouse clicks. However, if I have collapsed the div and fired an ajax call to update the div, I want the div to be in the expanded state as before. I have been trying to locate what is missing but unable to get it.
Css used:

```
.collapsibleContainerTitle div
{
padding: 5px 0 5px 19px;
background: url('images/bg_cpanel.png') top left no-repeat;
border-top-left-radius: 8px;
border-top-right-radius: 8px;
color: #00425f;
color: rgba(0, 66, 95, 1);
font-size: 1.25em;
}
.collapsibleContainerContent
{
padding: 10px;
}
.collapsibleContainerContent legend
{
display: none;
}
.collapsibleContainerTitle div {
background:url('images/bg_cpanel_expanded.jpg') top left no-repeat;
}
.collapsibleContainerTitleClosed div {
background:url('images/bg_cpanel_collapsed.jpg') top left no-repeat; 
}
.collapsibleContainerTitleDisable div {
background:url('images/bg_cpanel_disabled.jpg') top left no-repeat;
}
.collapsibleContainerContent {
padding:10px;
border:#EDEDED 1px solid;
}
.collapsibleContainerContent legend {
display:none;
}
```

And this is the collapsible panel area:

```
<fieldset style="width: 800px;" title="Search Results" id="fldRes" class="collapsibleContainer">
<div id="results">
<button id="btn1"> Generate </button>
</div></fieldset>
```

I am just writing this JS code:

```
$(".collapsibleContainer").next().show();
```

Please help. 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you get this code to jsFiddle, then could be easy for all. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery function `.next()` gets the next Sibling not descendent, so the sibling of `.collapibleContainer` will be `undefined` .... you could use `.find()` :

```
$(".collapsibleContainer").find('div').show();
```

Or [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(".collapsibleContainer").closest('div').show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/YQTxQ/

Comment: Wow....worked great with 


    $(".collapsibleContainer").find('div').show();

Thanks, ManseUK.